# MISRA checker wrong Inferring after passing pointer to function

Tags: c++, c++11, pass-by-reference, misra, unreachable-code

Somewhere in my project I have this code:

```
  {
    uint8_t u8Integer = 0xFFU;
    returnCode = someFucntion(&u8Integer); 
    uint8_t u8Decimal = 0xFFU;
    returnCode = someOtherFucntion(&u8Decimal);

    uint16_t u16Temp = ((static_cast<uint16_t>(u8Integer) << 8U) | static_cast<uint16_t>(u8Decimal));
      if(u16Temp <= 0xC000) // Problem here
      {
        // Uneracahble Code ?
      }
      else // {...}
  }
```

Both `someFucntion`and `someOtherFucntion` signatures look like this:

```
 int8_t someFucntion(uint8_t * pu8Data) const;
 int8_t someOtherFucntion(uint8_t * pu8Data) const;
```

An automatic MISRA static check throws an error saying that the `if` statement is never true.
I guess Is because the `u8Decimal`  and `u8Integer` are modified when passing their pointers to `someFucntion`and `someOtherFucntion` and the checker assumes they are still `0xFF` and therefore `u16Temp` will never change making it alwas `> 0xC000` .

When I run this program, the values of `u16Temp` change properly (sometimes entering the `if`statement and nometimes not).

the checker says "The inferred value of u16Temp is 65535"

Is this just a case where the checker is not working perfectly? Or do I actually have a code problem?

I tried setting the variables as `volatile` but this didn't work.

Comment: Be advised that quite a few of the MISRA tools out there are seriously borked.

Comment: thanks @MarkBenningfield I've noticed that :D it's a quite expensive one, but I'm wondering if , in this case, it actually detected something wrong in my code.

Comment: Nitpick and pedantry: if you're using `&u8Integer` then you're not passing by reference, you're passing a pointer to the location of `u8Integer` if `someFunction` has the signature `someFunction(uint8_t& foo)` then you're passing by reference. There is a major difference as you could in theory pass `nullptr` to what you have right now.

Comment: @Mgetz you're right, I'm editing , we can't have that kind of horrible mistakes in SO (?) xD

Comment: @Ivan we can... but honestly it might be affecting the checker. Depending on how it's parsing the tree, that could make big difference in how it interprets what's happening. If I wanted to be super nitpicky I'd call out using magic numbers in code 

Comment: Posting `someFucntion()` would help.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I thought the checker would only take into count the signature

Comment: @Ivan any decent checker will look at the whole thing, particularly given that a compiler may inline and eliminate a method.

Comment: Instead of placing many operations on one line, split it up to one operation per line.  This will give you better perspective as to which operation MISRA is complaining about.  Sometimes, the issue goes away by doing this practice.  The compiler will optimize the code as if it were on one line (use `const` as appropriate with the temp variables).

Comment: One issue is that `8U` is an unsigned integer which may be more bits than `uint16_t`.  To skirt this issue, declare a constant temporary variable to hold the `8U`:  `const uint16_t shift_quantity = 8U;`.  MISRA prefers all types to be the same in an expression (so that no casts are necessary).

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I'll try it

Comment: To me it appears that the checker is ignoring that `u8Integer` and `u8Digital` may be modified by the functions called... you haven't named the tool, but I suggest that you give their support desk some grief.